# Why doesn't asp.net download work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview, c#-3.0

I am using this code to download a image i.e. I am storing Image name with extension in database and getting it here.

this code throws no error but doesn't download anything. why ?

```
try {
    if (e.CommandName == "Download")
    {
        string ImgPath = Convert.ToString(r["Attachment"]);
        //string ImgName = r["ComplaintDetailID"].ToString() + "-" + r["LetterNo"].ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");

        //string filePath = ImgName + ".jpg";
        string fullFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/CMS/" + ImgPath);
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath));
        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
        Response.TransmitFile(fullFilePath); //downloads file
        Response.Flush();

        //FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fullFilePath);
        //file.Delete(); //deletes file after downloading
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ResultLabel.ResultLabelAttributes(ex.Message, ProjectUserControls.Enums.ResultLabel_Color.Red);
}
finally 
{
    ResultPanel.Controls.Add(ResultLabel);
}
```

Update:

i tried this but doesn't work.

```
 if (e.CommandName == "Download")
            {
                string ImgPath = Convert.ToString(r["Attachment"]);
                //string ImgName = r["ComplaintDetailID"].ToString() + "-" + r["LetterNo"].ToString() + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");


                        //string filePath = ImgName + ".jpg";
                        MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
                        File.OpenRead(ImgPath).CopyTo(m);
                        m.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);

                        string fullFilePath = Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/CMS/" + ImgPath);
                        Response.Clear();
                        Response.ClearHeaders();
                        Response.ClearContent();
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(fullFilePath));
                        Response.ContentType = ContentType;
                        Response.TransmitFile(fullFilePath); //downloads file
                        Response.Flush();

                        //FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fullFilePath);
                        //file.Delete(); //deletes file after downloading
            }
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: @शेखर no error, no exception, i tried debugging

Answer (score 0):

Create a Stream using following code

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
File.OpenRead(ImgPath ).CopyTo(m);
m.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
```

Comment: sorry I didn't get you  ?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track using `TransmitFile`. Check this line:

```
Response.ContentType = ContentType;
```

It looks like you're setting the `ContentType` to the page's default.

Try specifying it explicitly:

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```